# Several Routers and DMZ, WAN, Local LAN

Tags: router, dmz

I previously had:

- A PS3 directly connected to the router given to me by my ISP (Router A). I had the console in a DMZ on this router at IP 192.168.1.33
- So I had enabled UPnP for this router and setup DHCP for this router from 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.100, but set the console with a fixed IP of 192.168.1.33 to avoid conflict with the IPs seved by DHCP server, this has been working fine.
- A PS4 with several specific open ports from this router A and fixed IP at 192.168.1.34 (not important here)

Now my setup will be like this:

- I will take and connect the PS3 to a second router, Router B (located in a a different floor of the house), which is connected to Router A via Ethernet cable, so Router B is a client of Router A, and WAN for router B is just the regular connection coming from Router A.
- Note: I am making this problem simpler here, there is indeed a Router C connected to Router B and then the PS3 connected to Router C.
- Note 2: I need DHCP enabled on routers A, B and C because all three routers are in a different floor of the house and I need wifi and DHCP enabled for the mobiles and tablets in the house. There are so many houses and flats here (around the swimming pool) that getting a wifi signal from one of my routers not in the floor I am at the moment is almost impossible.
- I want full internet access for Router B so I will later be able to open/create a DMZ or opening ports in Router B so the PS3 will not suffer NAT issues. To achieve this: Router A (from my ISP) will have now DMZ open pointing to Router B's WAN IP 192.168.1.40 (the IP where it receives data from router A).
- Router B will have DHCP enabled, similar to what has been done in Router A, from 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.100, and PS3 will be now at 192.168.2.33
- As I want to create this DMZ in Router A pointing to Router B's WAN IP (let's say 192.168.1.40) I have to set Router B's WAN IP as 192.168.1.40, but ...... what would be the other data to set in Router B's WAN page (the data coming from Router A)???

> In Router A's WAN page I have this info (modified for privacy, but
>   let's suppose it is real)
>
> - WAN Address    65.125.71.62
> - Subnet Mask    255.255.214.0
> - Gateway Address    65.126.54.1
> - DNS Server 1   62.51.35.248
> - DNS Server 2   62.51.26.113
>
> Router A Private LAN page:
>
> - IP Private LAN      192.168.1.1
> - Subnet mask       255.255.255.0

What I know is that Router B will have the LAN IP address at 192.168.2.1 and will serve DHCP as I said from 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.100

So please, help me guessing the info I have to insert in Router B's WAN page - setting static IP address:

- IP Address   192.168.1.40 (I guess, as I do with the PS3 and PS4)
- Subnet mask  255.255.255.0 (I guess it is correct)
- Gateway Address 65.126.54.1 (I guess? this is my biggest doubt)
- DNS Server 1 62.51.35.248  (I guess)
- DNS Server 2 62.51.26.113 (I guess)

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is a pretty complex question!

As far as I can tell, you probably have most of it OK.

Except that the default gateway for Router B should be Router A's internal address not it's gateway address. Otherwise, with that netmask, you would never be able to route from inside Router B to Router A (and so would not be able to access the Internet).

You also seem to be moving the DHCP range from Router A to B so make sure you change that on A otherwise you will get clashes if anything is attached to A.

The subnet mask for A's WAN interface is wrong, it is very unlikely you will have that - only if you have multiple public IP addresses from your ISP. Other than that, the A WAN details are irrelevant for B & C. You should use the DNS settings though (though you might find Google or OpenDNS faster).

UPDATE: If A's **LAN** address is 192.168.1.1/24, then B's **WAN** address should be 192.168.1.x/24. It's LAN address should be 192.168.1.y/24, it may be that you will have to use A's DHCP to deliver B's WAN address if you cannot set it manually. Also, you need to make sure the B is not trying to log in to a non-existant ISP. It must have a plain, upstream ethernet port, sometimes referred to as an EWAN port.

If A's DHCP delivers 192.168.1.50-100, B's should deliver something like 192.168.1.101-200. Everything should have a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

You also need to ensure the B is passing through all traffic so set up appropriate firewall rules.

Don't try C until B is working & make sure that a device attached to B can route both to the Internet and to a device attached to A.

Note that it is perfectly possible that the B & C routers are not capable of supporting this configuration.

Comment: Thanks for replying: ||| 1) so Gateway WAN Router B should what? ||| 2) I am forced to put Router B's main IP at 192.168.2.1, previously I tried Router A main IP 192.168.1.1, DHCP from 192.168.1.50 -  192.168.1.100 and Router B main IP IP 192.168.1.2, DHCP from 192.168.1.101 -  192.168.1.120 and Router C main IP IP 192.168.1.3, DHCP from 192.168.1.121 -  192.168.1.141 but I could not access Router A's Panel Control from this computer connected to Router C. It looked logical to me but was not working properly, what do you think? || 3) Subnet mask Router A is ok, only 1 IP here.